# only one of three sliding tabs is showing data

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, tabs

I have three tabs, each of them should show specific data that was fetched from server. I have created only one fragment that is supposed to show different information based on which tab is open, however when app starts only one tab is showing data and after some time it crashes at the line when I am creating new NamesAdapter`

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "TabFragment";
    int page;
    private ArrayList<Names> namesList;
    NamesAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;


    public TabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static TabFragment newInstance(int page) {
        TabFragment fragment = new TabFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        namesList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        new MyTask().execute();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);


    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            String content = HttpManager.getData("http://union.ge/catalog/1455299520.json");

            Log.e("doInBackground", "was called");
            //return content;

            try {
                JSONArray json= new JSONArray(content);

                // get json objects one by one

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){

                    Names names = new Names();
                    // this json object now has key-value pairs and
                    JSONObject jRealObject = json.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("name");
                    //Log.e("jrealobject", jRealObject.toString());

                    names.setEn(jRealObject.getString("en"));
                    names.setGe(jRealObject.getString("ge"));
                    names.setRu(jRealObject.getString("ru"));

                    //migebuli monacemebi shevinaxot chvens array-shi
                    namesList.add(names);

                }

                return true;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;

        }

// on postExecute method runs on the UI thread

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
                super.onPostExecute(b);

                if(b){

                    adapter = new NamesAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, namesList, page);
                    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(page));

                    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "data was not parsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    }


}
```

`

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    final static int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private static final String TAG = "TabsAdapter";
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "EN", "GE", "RU" };
    private Context context;


    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return TabFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 1:
                return TabFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 2:
                return TabFragment.newInstance(2);
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment)object).getFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment)object);
        trans.commit();
    }



}
```

and the adapter for Names class

```
public class NamesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Names> {

    private static final String TAG = "NamesAdapter";
    ArrayList<Names> items;
    Context context;
    int resource;
    int page;

    LayoutInflater vi;


    public NamesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Names> items, int pageNumber) {
        super(context, resource, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.items = items;
        this.page = pageNumber;


        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){

           // convertView = vi.inflate(resource, null);
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        switch (page) {
            case 0:
                viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(position).getEn());
                break;
            case 1:
                viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(position).getGe());
                break;
            case 2:
                viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(position).getRu());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

Comment: paste logcat with which error app crashed in adapter?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310) at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)  at ge.mobility.anako.parser.NamesAdapter.<init>(NamesAdapter.java:33)at ge.mobility.anako.parser.TabFragment$MyTask.onPostExecute(TabFragment.java:111)at ge.mobility.anako.parser.TabFragment$MyTask.onPostExecute(TabFragment.java:62)

Comment: @AnaKoridze See my updated answer... Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change in MyTask.class as follows:

In `doInBackground()`, replace

> namesList.add(names);

with

> publishProgress(names);

And override this method

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    namesList.add(values[0])
}
```

---

The way you are creating an adapter is not correct. See this:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "TabFragment";
    private static final String PAGE_NO = "page_no";
    int page;
    private ArrayList<Names> namesList;
    NamesAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;


    public TabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static TabFragment newInstance(int page) {
        TabFragment fragment = new TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PAGE_NO, page);
        fragment .setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        namesList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

         page = getArguments().getInt(PAGE_NO);
         adapter = new NamesAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, namesList, page);
         Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(page));

         listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Start the task when view is created.
        new MyTask().execute();
    }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            String content = HttpManager.getData("http://union.ge/catalog/1455299520.json");

            Log.e("doInBackground", "was called");
            //return content;

            try {
                JSONArray json= new JSONArray(content);

                // get json objects one by one

                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){

                    Names names = new Names();
                    // this json object now has key-value pairs and
                    JSONObject jRealObject = json.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("name");
                    //Log.e("jrealobject", jRealObject.toString());

                    names.setEn(jRealObject.getString("en"));
                    names.setGe(jRealObject.getString("ge"));
                    names.setRu(jRealObject.getString("ru"));

                    //migebuli monacemebi shevinaxot chvens array-shi
                    publishProgress(names);

                }

                return true;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            namesList.add(values[0]);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


            // on postExecute method runs on the UI thread
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
                super.onPostExecute(b);

                if(!b){
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "data was not parsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            }
    }


}
```

Comment: it does the same thing, I mean, when I click first tab, sometimes it shows second tab elements, sometimes third tab elements, with no logic

Comment: Is the `NullPointerException` you was facing before, is it appearing now?

Comment: And I don't understand where and why use are using `page` variable.

Comment: I wan to use some parameter to check which tab is open to display relevant information on listView

Comment: Okay, `TabFragment ` is used in 3 different tabs. And same API is being used for each tab. That's  why same data is displayed. Change the API based on the page number.

Comment: what should I do more specifically?